# Bash script to get the result from rsync transfer and zip it as a directory in the original directory

Tags: bash, rsync, zip, deployment

OK, I guess this is weird.
I have a small stage.sh script very simply has a bunch of commands:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" == 'David' ]; then
    rsync -a --delete-excluded --exclude-from=.rsyncrc $(pwd) ~/Sites/local-testing-0/modules/
    rsync -a --delete-excluded --exclude-from=.rsyncrc $(pwd) ~/Sites/local-testing-1/modules/
    rsync -a --delete-excluded --exclude-from=.rsyncrc $(pwd) ~/Sites/local-testing-7/modules/
    rsync -a --delete-excluded --exclude-from=.rsyncrc $(pwd) ~/Sites/local-testing-2/modules/
    echo "Checked out for David"
fi
```

And there are also other cases according to the current logged-in user. Note that the source is the current directory (see the $(pwd)). I want to add a case that takes the current directory and makes a **zipped folder** out it. By zipped folder I mean no [tarbomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Tarbomb), and it must be in zip format. I'd want to take the output of the rsync transfer, because it already filters stuff. I tried using named pipes. I could also use the file `.rsyncrc` for exclusions in the tar/zipping process. It reads like this:

```
# Meta
- stage.sh
- .rsyncrc

# Repo itself
- .git
- .gitignore

# Distribution Packages
- dist/

# Other files
- */.DS_Store
```

So if I could just use this file for exclusion in the zipping process, than it would be great too. I didn't really test this, but I'm not sure it's possible. The output should be placed in ./dist/, which is excluded from the rsync/zipping process.

**Bonus points** if the name of the output zip filename had a version number -suffix, taken from inside the file that has the same name of the folder with ".php" appended. The line with the version number is always like this: `$this->version = '0.0.1';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this `build.sh` script:

```
foldername=$(dirname $(pwd))
projname=$(basename $(pwd))
rsync -a --exclude-from=.rsyncrc $(pwd) $TMPDIR
cd $TMPDIR
zip -rq $foldername/$projname/dist/$projname-latest.zip $projname
cd $foldername/$projname
```

It resides in the root folder, so that whenever I want to package in zip the whole project, I run `source build.sh` and there it goes, in my *dist/* folder as *projectname*-latest.zip

Comment: $TMPDIR is available on OS X, I don't know if it's available on other OSes

Comment: It is not a default environment variable, no, but it is widely used in UNIX systems. Though the POSIX standardized version is `TMPDIR`